# How to programatically change the DNS servers in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, debian, fedora

I have this app that is supposed to change the DNS servers of a Linux machine programatically but I can't seem to find a proper way to do it. Some versions are good with updating `resolv.conf`, others only work if you play with `netplan` etc. Is there a proper way of doing this thing that works on all instances?

So far I found these options:

`resolv.com` - works on some instances but it is ineffective on others

`netplan` - only used and present on newer versions of ubuntu (and possibly others) so I can't rely on it being effective either

changing `dns-nameservers` inside `/etc/network/interfaces` - I have to restart the network after that and I'm still not sure it's a solution that works

Which route do you guys suggest I should go or is there something that I'm missing? How does one programatically change the DNS servers of a box?

Answer (score 2):

How to resolve the requested task is highly distribution dependent. Therefore there is no standard way of doing it properly which matches different distributions.

In case of `Debian` and `Ubuntu` it should be save to use `/etc/network/interfaces`.

In case of `Red Hat Enterprise Linux`, `CentOs`, `Fedora` related files are found in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts`.